# Как просмотреть в отладке очень большую строковую переменную в Android Studio

Tags: c++, android-studio, android-ndk

Имеется очень длинная строковая переменная, содержимое которой я пытаюсь посмотреть в отладке. Окно отладки обрезает ее содержимое до определенной длинны и дальше посмотреть не получается.
[image: окно просмотра содержимого переменной]

Comment: Напиши мини функцию которая, возьмет длину переменной. И разобьет ее на n частей вернет из них в некий массив все части. а потом смотри их по очереди. Это будет как бы функция для теста, и не будет иметь отношения к проекту.

Comment: Не знаю как в Android Studio, но в идешках от Jetbrains можно раскрывать большие переменные в отдельное окошко, поищите у себя

Comment: Так поменяй IDE =) Qt Creator ничего не обрезает, например

Comment: @dIm0n, на скриншоте как раз это окошко и открыто)

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον, тут на плюсах только ядро приложения, остальное на java, вариант с другой IDE не подойдет(

Comment: @Dante_Attano посмотрел у себя только что - да, окошко похоже, только справа слайдер есть для прокрутки вниз. Мб у вас можно на `...` нажать или типа того? Если нет, то боюсь вам остаётся только разрабам писать :)